# Approximation of continuous functions by Lipschitz functions in the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, approximation-theory

I was involved into this subject when I answered
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592596/approximation-of-bounded-and-continuous-mappings)
question from MSE. Trying to generalize my answer, I am thinking about a following

*Question.* Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces. When each continuous function
from $X$ to $Y$ can be approximated by Lipschitz functions
in the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets?

It seems that I can prove that the question has a positive answer provided a pair
$(X,Y)$ satisfies the following

*Condition.* Each bounded (that is with finite diameter of the image) function from $A$ to $Y$ defined on a uniformly discrete subset $A$ of the space $X$
can be extended to a Lipschitz function from $X$ to $Y$. (I call a subset $A$ of a metric space
$(X,d)$ *uniformly discrete,* provided there exists a number $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$d(x,y)\ge\varepsilon$ for each distinct points $x,y\in A$.)
In particular, Valentine Theorem (see, [p. 11, LR] or [V]) implies that
a pair $(X,Y)$ satisfies Condition provided $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces.

We found no references on the above results and I think about a publication and
a continuation of this investigation. But I am not a specialist in this domain.

So, I care about the following questions. *Are the above results new, good
and worthy to be published somewhere? What another related problems are worthy to be investigated?
In particular, is it known which pairs $(X,Y)$ of metric spaces satisfies Condition?*

Thanks.

*References*

[LR] Ronnie Levy, Michael David Rice.
*[The approximation and extension of uniformly continuous Banach space valued
mappings](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/106224)*, Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae,
**24**:2 (1983), 251--265.

[V] F.A. Valentine, *A Lipschitz condition preserving extension for a vector function,* Amer. J.
Math., **67** (1945), 83--93.

*Related questions*

[Approximation by locally Lipschitz functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43625/approximation-by-locally-lipschitz-functions)

[explicit extention of Lipschitz function (Kirszbraun theorem)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64511/explicit-extention-of-lipschitz-function-kirszbraun-theorem)

Comment: There's no hypothesis about having a uniform bound on the Lipschitz numbers of the approximating functions?

Comment: @NikWeaver It seems that if $f=\lim f_n$, where all $f_n$ are $L$-Lipschitz then the function $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz too.

Comment: So you're assuming there is a uniform bound on the Lipschitz numbers of the approximating functions.

Comment: @NikWeaver It seems that if I assume this then the limit function will be Lipschitz and the question will be trivial. So I do not assume this.

Comment: You could have just answered "no" to my first question, but okay. I believe the result, if correct, is new, and I think it is publishable.

Comment: Can I ask if the result was published, so that it is available for quoting?

Comment: @erz It is hard question. My [professor, who had both his thesises in functional analysis](http://www.franko.lviv.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/bancv.html), said that the subject is widely investigated, so such results should be known, and, therefore, not publishable. I did not find a reference for the above results and I cannot propose to the professor to find it. But I think that the proof should be easy and I can write it, for instance, as a lemma for your paper.